# What is the name of this antenna?

Tags: rf, identification, antenna, ground-plane, ham-radio

I compared RSSI of several antennas including this one I found laying around:

[image: Unknown Antenna]

It performed from all angles about 10 dB better than for example the quarter wave ANT-433-CW-HD-SMA ([Mouser Link](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Linx-Technologies/ANT-433-CW-HD-SMA?qs=1sbE9T7hb3YD4o8QUTh5Rg%3D%3D)).

Tests were performed without a groundplane.

Is this a no-groundplane antenna? Can anyone find out the name or producer of the antenna? If not, does someone know of similar antennas?

Comment: Does this antenna require a power source?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: At 88mm, selling the ANT-433-CW-HD-SMA as a "quarter-wave whip" is a blatant lie. It's 1/8 wavelength long including radome, and presumably less than that internally. It's a normal-mode helical whip ("rubber duck").

Comment: Suggest you right click on the image, the search with Google Lens - it found several similar antennas available. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not appear to be a no-groundplane antenna, you can see a threaded hole where a ground plane radial would screw in. They come out at around a 45 degree angle and there is usually 3 or 4 of them.

It appears to be a quarter wave ground plane, basically a quarter wave vertical radiator with several grounded radials at the bottom. You can measure the radiator length to get an idea of what frequency it is for.

Comment: Nice catch with the screw holes for the ground plane radials, thanks!

By length, it could very well be a quarter-wave antenna for the 70 cm band.